# Django-selectize not showing all the tags created with django-taggit

Tags: python, django, django-taggit, selectize.js

I have a model that uses tags with django-taggit as shown on the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/xpostudio4/76c69bb072f7eb1599fe) , the problem I have is that The form is rendered in the view with multiple values in the tagged field but only one does appear when the template is rendered. Can somebody explain me why this happen?
[image]

[image]

Comment: whats the template code? also did you verify that template does not render other tags and not UI library (maybe js script) is swallowing other tags?

Comment: Certainly the Js is changing the elemenent, when I comment out selectize all the items do appear on the form field.